# HereMaps SDK ,Class "MapMarker" object not listing InfoBubble Function In android

Tags: android, here-api

I want to implement info Bubble On android and i am referring to https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/MapMarker.html#showInfoBubble--

But My object not returning Member Functions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx66Q.png)

Comment: You're probably using Premium version of the SDK but provided doc link to the Starter version of the SDK. Premium version of the SDK does not have this functionality, instead you should use MapOverlay class to show info view.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments InfoBubble is not supported by HERE Mobile Premium SDK , it is supported in HERE Starter SDK however the Starter SDK is now deprecated.

Alternative for HERE Mobile Premium SDK on Android would be the MapOverlay class ([documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-objects-and-interaction.html))

```
private Button button;

private void onMapFragmentInitializationCompleted() {
  // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
  map = mapFragment.getMap();
  // Set the map center coordinate to the Vancouver region (no animation)
  map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(49.196261, -123.004773, 0.0),
      Map.Animation.NONE);
  // Set the map zoom level to the average between min and max (no
  // animation)
  map.setZoomLevel((map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
  // create the button
  button = new Button(this);
  button.setText("TEST");
  // create overlay and add it to the map
  map.addMapOverlay(
      new MapOverlay(button,
          new GeoCoordinate(37.77493, -122.419416, 0.0)));
```